# Error when trying to create a field on the Standard Object: Approval Request

Tags: approval-process, standard-objects, advanced-approvals

I am trying to create a field on the standar Approval Request object but I get the following error:

Unable to Access Page

The value of the "entity" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You cannot access 'Approval Request' object on UI, Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdcu4UAB/approval-processes-approval-request-object-not-visible-to-maintain-in-setup) and vote for this feature.

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstanceworkitem.htm), you can access using ProcessInstanceWorkItem via API.

> Exceptions apply to approval history data retrieved with this object and are available only via SOAP API.